# 10e notation used with variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

I want to know how can I use the 10eX notation in python 2.7.9 with a variable. 
In terms of literals 10eX gives (10^X).00000(floating point number).
I want to use some variable instead of literal, however, and it does not work. 
What syntactical change should I make if it is possible to do so or is there any other way to do so?
Thanks in advance!

```
T = int(raw_input())
while T:
    N = int(raw_input())
    LIS = map(int,raw_input().split())
    num_lis, num = []*N, []*N
    low = int(10e+(N))
    high = int(10e+(N+1))
    temp, count = 0, 0
    for i in xrange(low,high):
        num_lis = [1]*N
        temp = i
        while temp!=0:
            r = temp%10
            num[high-1-i] = r
            temp=temp/10        
        for p in xrange[1,N]:
            for q in xrange(0,p):
                if num[q]<num[p]:
                    if num_lis[p]<(num_lis[q]+1):
                        num_lis[p]=num_lis[q]+1
            if LIS[p]!=num_lis[p]:
                break
            else:
                count++
    print count
    T-=1
```

On running the interpreter I get error for-
10e(N)    :    Invalid Syntax

Comment: Mind that `10eX` is not equal to `10^X`, but `10*10^X`.

Comment: `10e1` in the python console says `100`, which is logical because of *Engineering notation*,

Comment: Python uses `**` for Exponentiation, not `^`, so you need to use `10**N` not `10e+(N)`. `^` in Python means Bitwise OR.

Comment: Oh, right. I'm thinking of 1eX.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`10e+4`is a notation for `10 * 10^4`, not an operation. You have to use the power-operator:

```
low = 10 ** (N+1)
high = 10 ** (N+2)
```

Comment: not to mention that using `int(math.pow(10,N))` leads to floating point inaccuracy when N is high.

Answer (score 3):

Something like `10e3` is a float literal. You could create it as a string and then use `float()` to convert it to a number (and `int(float())` if you wanted to convert that number to an int):

```
>>> N = raw_input()
3
>>> float("10e"+N)
10000.0
>>> #compare:
>>> 10e3
10000.0
```

It is probably better to use the answer of @Daniel, but the above seems closer to what you were trying to do with `int(10e+(N))` since you were explicitly asking about literals which depend on variables.

Comment: doing this with a big N leads to floating point inaccuracy.`int(10E+30)
= 9999999999999999635896294965248`

Comment: I don't really recommend this, but they asked what syntactical change they would have to make to be able to create literals of the requisite form with a variable exponent. Answer: construct it as a string.