# Python why is 10e26 != 10**26 ? (Floating point inaccuracy?)

Tags: python, floating-point, notation

I was trying to process some rather large numbers in python and came across an overflow error. I decided to investigate a little bit more and came across an inequality I cannot explain.
When I evaluate 10^26 I get:

```
>>> 10**26
100000000000000000000000000
```

Which is perfectly logical. However when I evaluate 10e26 and convert it to an int I get:

```
>>>int(10e26)
1000000000000000013287555072
```

Why is this?
Do I not understand the e notation properly? (From what I know 10e26 is 10*10^26 as seen in this answer: [10e notation used with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794135/10e-notation-used-with-variables))

10^26 is way past the max integer size so I was also wondering if there was any mechanism in python which could allow to work with numbers in scientific format (not considering all those zeros) in order to be able to compute operations with numbers past the max size.

Comment: There is no max integer size in Python; `int` can represent an arbitrarily large integer, subject only to the available memory to store the value. `10**26` (since both operands are `int` literals) evaluates to an `int` as well. `10e26`, on the other hand, is a `float` literal, and `float` is limited in which integer values it can precisely represent.

Comment: I'm not clear on why this happens despite being familiar with that dupe target. Why is the syntax handling this differently? This could be done internally with only integers?

Comment: Nm, it's answered in the question the OP linked. `10e26` is a float literal. Knowing that is sufficient to understand the dupe.

Comment: The normal floating point inaccuracy would make sense, but wouldn't the interpreter be a little smarter in its conversion to int? Or does that simply mean that 10.0 in float is represented by 10.00000000000000013287555072?

Comment: @A.D. 10.0 can be represented precisely as a floating-point value, because there is enough precision in the mantissa to store a small integer exactly. `10e26`, however, is too large to be stored exactly in the mantissa, and so has to be stored as a smaller approximate mantissa with an appropriate exponent.

Comment: Folks, please do the math before marking something as a duplicate. `10e26` is not equal to `10**26` because the former represents 10 times 10^26, which is 10^27, and the latter represents 10^26. This difference has nothing to do with floating-point.

Comment: Furthermore, if somebody had asked about `1e26 == 10^26`, knowing about the floating-point format in insufficient; one also has to know how Python evaluations expressions (such as which arithmetics are used for `1e26` and for `10^26` and what format or algorithm is used for the comparison), so a general floating-point question is inadequate. [The question marked as an original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) does not address these adequately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that `10e26` and `10**26` do *not* represent identical values.

`10**26`, with both operands being `int` values, evaluates to an `int`. As `int` represents integers with arbitrary precision, its value is *exactly* 10<sup>26</sup> as intended.

`10e26`, on the other hand, is a `float` literal, and as such the resulting value is subject to the limited precision of the `float` type on your machine. The result of `int(10e26)` is the integer value of the `float` closest to the real number 10<sup>27</sup>.

Comment: Ah alright, that makes more sense and 10**27.0 does evaluate to 10e26. I'll accept that !

Answer (score 4):

`10e26` represents ten times ten to the power of 26, which is 10<sup>27</sup>.

`10**26` represents represents ten to the power of 26, 10<sup>26</sup>.

Obviously, these are different, so `10e26 == 10**26` is false.

However, if we correct the mistake so we compare `1e26` and `10**26` by evaluating `1e26 == 10**26`, we get false for a different reason:

- `1e26` is evaluated in a limited-precision floating-point format, producing 100000000000000004764729344 in most implementations. (Python is not strict about the floating-point format.) 100000000000000004764729344 is the closest one can get to 10<sup>26</sup> using 53 significant bits.
- `10**26` is evaluated with integer arithmetic, producing 100000000000000000000000000.
- Comparing them reports they are different.

(I am uncertain of Python semantics, but I presume it converts the floating-point value to an extended-precision integer for the comparison. If we instead convert the integer to floating-point, with `float(10**26) == 1e26`, the conversion of 100000000000000000000000000 to `float` produces the same value, 100000000000000004764729344, and the comparison returns true.)

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to convert the floating point to large integer: it might be faster to check if the int can be converted to float exactly. First check that highBit does not exceed maximum float exponent (case of overflow), and if not, then compute how many bits span the integer significand (highBitRank - lowBitRank + 1) and check if it exceeds float precision (24 or 53 bits for standard IEEE). See method isAnExactFloat in http://source.squeak.org/trunk/Kernel-nice.853.diff. I did not check Python implementation though, but could be same spirit.

Comment: On Python semantics: the actual details are messy, but yes, Python jumps through hoops to compare the exact values correctly. The current code (for CPython, at least), starts here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62c35a8a8ff5854ed470b1c16a7a14f3bb80368c/Objects/floatobject.c#L332