# 1e400 == 10**400 is False?

Tags: python, integer, overflow, precision, exponent

In Python, `1e400` evaluates to `inf`, but `10**400` prints out just fine. Theoretically, 1e(x) is supposed to be `10**x`, but why and when does this break down?

In a related vein, `1e5 == 10**5` evaluates to `True`, while `1e40 == 10**40` evaluates to `False`. Then while `int(1e22)` shows a 1 with 22 zeros, `int(1e23)` shows `99999999999999991611392`. Meanwhile, `10**100000` is still printing out just fine. (Although ten to the million is freezing up my computer, it still isn't giving me an overflow error.)

What's behind this inaccuracy? Is `1e()` inferior to `10**()`?

Comment: I think OP is right that this not a duplicate of the 'Is floating point math broken' post, since this requires knowledge of float literals and Python formatting. This question is probably a better duplicate of [Python why is 10e26 != 10**26 ? (Floating point inaccuracy?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353247/python-why-is-10e26-1026-floating-point-inaccuracy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using different types

```
print (type(1e5))    # float
print (type(10**5))  # int
```

Int can get arbitrarily  big in python .. float ... not so much.