Printing matrices in Python in customized format
I have many matrices such as a below generated in a Python program and need to output them in a specific form.
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1/10000009, 2, 3], [3, 4/3000897, 5]])
print(a)

This will print
[[9.99999100e-08 2.00000000e+00 3.00000000e+00]
 [3.00000000e+00 1.33293479e-06 5.00000000e+00]]

However, I need to print it as
{{9.99999100*^-08, 2.00000000*^+00, 3.00000000*^+00},{3.00000000*^+00, 1.33293479^*-06, 5.00000000*^+00}}

i.e., the matrix structure is indicated by { , , , } at any level and in scientific notation e is replaced by *^.
How to do this?
A closely related question is what if a is a list of lists like a=[[1/10000009, 2, 3], [3, 4/3000897, 5]] instead of np.array above.

Start by formatting one number.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41794160/7508077

You can pass the reference to your numpy.ndarray to str() to get its string representation.
Then just translate the string as follows:
import numpy as np

translator = str.maketrans({"e": "*^", "[": "{", "]": "}", " ": ", ", "\n": ""})

a = np.array([[1 / 10000009, 2, 3], [3, 4 / 3000897, 5]])

print(str(a).translate(translator).replace(" {", "{"))

Output:
{{9.99999100*^-08, 2.00000000*^+00, 3.00000000*^+00},{3.00000000*^+00, 1.33293479*^-06, 5.00000000*^+00}}


Thanks, but how should I put all the commas? The format { , , , , } is important to me.

@xiaohuamao I misread your output requirement. Code edited

This is indeed a nice solution. But when I tried it on the real data I have, I noticed an issue: the spaces Python puts in the arrays are sometimes irregular for unknown reasons, e.g., like [[ 9.99999100e-08 2.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00]  [ 3.00000000e+00  1.33293479e-06 5.00000000e+00 ]]. The code then fails. Is there any remedy for this?

@xiaohuamao Yes there is a remedy. Scan the string for multiple adjacent spaces and convert such sequences to one space

you can create two functions to format matrix and for each value, format element (import numpy):
def format_matrix(matrix):
    # Convert each element of the matrix to the specified format
    formatted_matrix = [[format_element(elem) for elem in row] for row in matrix]
    # Join elements with commas and rows with commas
    formatted_str = ','.join(['{' + ','.join(row) + '}' for row in formatted_matrix])
    return formatted_str

def format_element(elem):
    # Convert to scientific notation format
    formatted_elem = "{:.8e}".format(elem)
    # Replace 'e' with '*^'
    formatted_elem = formatted_elem.replace('e', '*^')
    return formatted_elem

And then you just do:
formatted_a = format_matrix(a)

